# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Access local folder only on server side without exposing to web

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have been going around the houses on this one and now can't see the wood for the trees, so wanted to seek opinions on the best way of achieving without compromising security.

We have some static files stored in a local folder on the web server (eg. currently `c:\staticfiles`) and need the ability for our `ASP.Net Core 2.0` app to access these, but only from the server side.  I don't want to place them under `www` (or anywhere else externally visible) as this would make them publicly accessible.

With our current settings, we are getting "`Access to the path is denied`" exception from the server side code despite the permissions we have applied (even "Everyone" as a test) to the `c:\staticfiles` folder.

Would really appreciate thoughts.
Thanks.

Comment: would all the clients have direct access to browse those files direct? or you could put them in a hidden folder on the web, that is there but only if you know where to find it and even put a password protect on it

Comment: Unfortunately the info contained within is too sensitive to chance that.  It's only needed for server-side processing and must only be accessible by the "code behind".

Comment: Oh oK - then it should be just a simple permissions for the code base to let them access them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this in the ASP.NET framework, there was call "Server.MapPath" which used to map to the files on the file system.   In .net core, this API can not be used.

In .net core, there are two concepts

- Content root, for binaries and private files
- web root, this is for public files which are to be exposed through URL.

By default, both of these locations point to the same folder.

You can change the location of content root or web root by using [IHostingEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-2.2) interface OR [the hosting.json file](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-replacement-for-servermappath).

The links are inline if you need references.

The stack overflow should help you [to understand hosting.json schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892173/hosting-json-available-options).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but is this more concerned with where the files are located as opposed to actually accessing them? This infers I should move my content into the "Content root" as opposed to leaving them where they are allowing access.

Comment: If I can get access to the files (ie. get passed the Access is denied error) by placing the folder under www, then perhaps I could use a config change for IIS to prevent that specific folder from being served?!

Comment: This is to clarify that you can create your private files inside the content root, but your content root and web root should not be same directory.  That way you will be able to keep them safe and your code will be able to access them.

Comment: Will investigate further, thank you. Slightly concerned this will mean we have to move a whole bunch of binaries over too though that allow the site to continue working, or are you suggesting this can just be used for my specific use-case and nothing else will need to change? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep the same folder for webroot and contentroot, then there is another option of blocking the URLs (which access those paths) by the use of  HTTP modules or custom middleware.

Comment: I'm taking the kind answer from Manoj because that gave me a nudge to start thinking about the IHostingEnvironment.  So essentially I am using that for the content root and simply not allowing access to the "sensitive" folder from an IIS perspective.

Comment: Glad this helped !